# Can I find the timestamp of the last value change

Tags: prometheus

Given a time series, is it possible to find the timestamp of the last value change?

For example, a cron job runs every night. It first runs an rsync job, and later computes the size of the target directory. The actual metric value is not all that significant, but I would like to verify that it actually changes every night.

Is it possible to create a query that return a scalar value with the timestamp of the last value change?

Comment: This question and first answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148451/get-time-that-passed-since-the-last-increase-of-prometheus-counter?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

For many use cases, there are workarounds. For mine, there isn't.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to handle this is to push a metric whose value is the unix timestamp that the batch jobs succeeded at. You can then alert on that value being recent enough.

https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-batch-jobs-in-python/ has a Python example.

Comment: Yes, I know about that one. But is does not really answer my question: Is it possible to query the data store for the timestamp of the last value change?

(To clarify: It is quite possible that the batch job runs properly, e.g. that it copied all the data from the remote server. However, by monitoring for "change of value" (directory size), you would also detect anomalies in the generation process on the remote server)

Comment: No, you can't currently get that. Thus you'd add a metric as I suggested.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I will stop looking!

(But note that adding a metric like you suggested does not solve my problem. The batch job works exactly as expected, with successful completing every night. I'm trying to detect the scenario where the underlying data does not change; hence looking for timestamp of last value change).

Comment: (I initially accepted the answer, but undid it. The answer suggests a workaround that does not work for me, and only the further discussions brings out the answer of "No, you can't do that")

Answer (score 2):

To get timestamp of last metric's change you can use query like this

```
last_over_time(
 timestamp(
  changes(
   grafana_http_request_duration_seconds_count{handler=~"/api/playlists/", method="GET"}[1m]
  ) > 0
 )[30d:]
)
```

Here:

- `grafana_http_request_duration_seconds_count{handler=~"/api/playlists/", method="GET"}` simply an example of metric,
- `changes( ... [1m] ) > 0` returns number of changes over the minute, if there were any present. Notice, that range used here should be more that `scrape_interval`,
- `timestamp( ... )` - returns timestamp associated with result of last function. Notice, that this is not a timestamp of actual change, but only of "window frame" associated with evaluation of function `change`,
- `last_over_time( ... [30d:])` to "stretch out" results. Returns the last present timestamp of inner functions.

Also, remember, that this wouldn't be an exact timestamp of last chenge, but rather last change will occur somewhere within rang `[t-1m, t]`, where `t` is returned value, and `1m` is range selector used inside of `changes` function.

Demo of this query can be seen [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=grafana_http_request_duration_seconds_count%7Bhandler%3D%7E%22%2Fapi%2Fplaylists%2F%22%2C%20method%3D%22GET%22%7D&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=2w&g1.expr=last_over_time(timestamp(changes(grafana_http_request_duration_seconds_count%7Bhandler%3D%7E%22%2Fapi%2Fplaylists%2F%22%2C%20method%3D%22GET%22%7D%5B1m%5D)%3E0)%5B30d%3A%5D)&g1.tab=0&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=2w).

---

Regarding your scenario: I wouldn't use that much complicated query. To verify that metric changes you can merely compare it with itself offseted by some time.

```
my_metric != my_metric offset 8h
```

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus provides [changes](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#changes) function, which can be used for determining the number of changes for time series samples over the given lookbehind window in square brackets. For example, the following query returns the number of sample value changes for time series with the name `metric_name` during the last 5 minutes:

```
changes(metric_name[5m])
```

Zero changes can be filtered out by adding `> 0` to the query. The following query returns non-empty result only if there was at least a single sample value change during the last 5 minutes:

```
changes(metric_name[5m]) > 0
```

Unfortunately, Prometheus doesn't provide the functionality for returning the timestamp for the last non-empty value :(

If you still need to get the timestamp for the last value change, then [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) may come to rescue with [tlast_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#tlast_over_time) function. The following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query returns the timestamp of the last value change for `metric_name` with 1 minute precision if the change was made during the last 24 hours:

```
tlast_over_time(changes(metric_name[5m])[24h:1m])
```

This query uses [subquery feature](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#subqueries).

P.S. VictoriaMetrics provides [tlast_change_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#tlast_change_over_time) function starting from v1.77.0. This function returns the timestamp in seconds for the last value change on the given lookbehind window in square brackets. For example, the following query is mostly equivalent to the query above. The only difference is that it returns the exact timestamp for the raw sample with the last change:

```
tlast_change_over_time(metric_name[24h])
```