# Monitor number of seconds since metric change as prometheus time series

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

This was already partially answered in [get time that passed since the last increase of Prometheus counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148451)

But not sufficiently, so I'm asking here and in the Prometheus Google Group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/prometheus-users/I7gJ15BIvXg/jFlxOSppBAAJ

--

I have the Recording rule pattern:

```yaml
  - record: last-update
    expr: |
      timestamp(changes(metric-name[450s]) > 0)
        or
      last-update
    labels:
      stat: true
      monitor: false
```

However, that doesn't work. The `or last-update` part doesn't return a value.

I have tried using an offset,
`or (last-update offset 450s)`, 
to no avail.

My evaluation frequency is 5 minutes (the frequency that prometheus runs my Recording rules). I tried the 7.5 minutes offset because I theorized that the OR was attempting to write last-update as last-update but last-update was null in that second; if the OR were to attempt writing last-update as the value it was during it's previous evaluation, then it should find a value in last-update, but that returned no value as well.

This is what the metric looks like graphed:

[choppy rather than a complete staircase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ljab.png) (I don't have enough reputation to post pictures...)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Why I care:
If a time series plateaus for an extended period of time then I want to know as that may mean it has begun to fail to return accurate data.

Comment: Did you try a lower evaluation frequency ? 5min is too near the metric TTL.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Forgive me, what does TTL stand for? Something about metric timeout? (https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter/pull/164)
Are you thinking that last-update goes stale in those 5 minutes and therefore is not capable of being referenced by the Recording Rule?
@MichaelDoubez

Comment: Yes, I am refering to [staleness](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) of metrics: they have a Time To Live (TTL) of 5 minutes. I suspect the second part of the `OR` doesn't yield any data because it is already staled.

Comment: Thank you for the link on staleness. That was a necessary step towards a solution.

Now I can't get passed the `vector contains metrics with the same labelset after applying rule labels`.

I do add labels in the recording rule:
```
                  stat: true
                  monitor: false
```

I believe this is because `last-update` already has all the labels that `metric-name` has plus the labels that the recording rule adds, so when the `or` is triggered `last-update` conflicts since it already has the labels.

How do I get around this? Thank you again for your creativity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up our discussion: the evaluation interval is too big; after 5 minutes, a metric becomes [stale](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness). This means that when the expression is evaluated, the right hand side of your `OR` expression is no longer considered by Prometheus and thus is always empty.

Your second issue is that your record rule is adding some labels to the original metric and you get some complaint by Prometheus. This is not because the labels already exists: in [recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/#rule), labels overwrite the existing labels.

The issue is your `OR` expression: it should specify an `ignoring()` [matching clause](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches) for ignoring the added labels or you will get the labels from both sides of the `OR` expression:

> `vector1 or vector2` results in a vector that contains all original elements (label sets + values) of vector1 and additionally all elements of vector2 ***which do not have matching label sets in vector1***.

Since you get both sides of the `OR`, when Prometheus tries to add the labels to the left hand side, it conflicts with the right hand side which already exists.

Your expression should be something like:

```yaml
    expr: |
      timestamp(changes(metric-name[450s]) > 0)
        or ignoring(stat,monitor)
      last-update
```

Or use an `ON(label1,label2,...)` clause on a discriminating label set which avoids changing the expression whenever you change the labels.

Comment: Thank you Michael! I am in business! Your time philanthropy is appreciated