# Timestamp of last prometheus metric change

Tags: timestamp, prometheus, grafana, metrics

I am using Grafana and prometheus and I am trying to get the timestamp at which a given metric last had it’s value changed. Based on information found here : [get time that passed since the last increase of Prometheus counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148451/get-time-that-passed-since-the-last-increase-of-prometheus-counter), I tried several queries in prometheus server interface like :

```
timestamp(changes(up{job="prometheus"}[1h]) > 0) * 1000
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the timestamp at which my metric last changed it’s value.
I either get query execution errors when trying to filter results, or end up getting the timestamp of the last time the metric was scraped.

Can someone tell me if this is possible using PromQL. Or if there is a way to do this in Grafana ?

Comment: You need to change range selector to something smaller, like `1m`, and wrap it with `last_over_time( ... [30d])`. Full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76733028/21363224).